# How do I go from Vientiane to Chiang Mai?

Tags: buses, thailand, laos, vientiane, chiang-mai

I heard that there are buses available for me to travel from Vientiane to Chiang Mai. The only problem is that I don't think there are websites or agencies that have services to book the tickets.

May I know how I could prepare myself on the traveling plan before I get there in August?

Answer (score 2):

When taking international buses in Asia, there is in most cases no direct connection, specially when the cities are not connected with a direct straight road. It's better to look for 2 or more connections to get you there.

Same in this case. You can take a bus from the [Vientiane Central Bu](http://www.travelfish.org/transport/laos/vientiane_and_surrounds/vientiane/vientiane/all)s station to to Khon Kaen:

> Khon Kaen 08:15, 14:45. Price: 50,000 kip, 4-5 hours

and then from there another one [to Chiang Mai](http://thetradingtravelers.com/bus-travel-from-khon-kaen-to-chiang-mai/).

Now when it comes to preparation and buying bus tickets in advance, you are out of luck. You are in a very local territory here and won't be able to reserve bus tickets, let alone in English. So you will have to make sure that you prepare yourself with some internet translation of the name of the city and the term "bus" as well as "ticket" on printed paper and use that to find the ticket counter and then to get a ticket.

At least you will know that there IS a bus, how often it goes and what you expect to pay for it.

Comment: Actually you will find enough English spoken and written at the Vientiane and Khon Kaen bus stations to find and buy tickets.  But online advance booking is not readily available.

Comment: There's travel agents selling all kinds of bus tickets here in Vientiane and also many if not most hostels, guesthouses, and hotels also sell bus tickets.